# TextView shrinking and ellipsis issue

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView in my layout. I just wanted to make its text with this properties:

```
Singleline - Yes
Shrinking - Yes
Ellipsis - No
```

My problem is when I set the textview as singleline, it automatically has an ellipsis property.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a way to do it with XML alone; you have to do it after the XML has been inflated by calling `textView.setEllipsize(null);`

Answer (score 0):

You habe to change the property once the view is drawn.

For ex-
tv.setEllipsize(null);